# READ or READ INTO

Tags: cobol

In quite a few COBOL tutorials about file reading, I see that they use the READ *fd* INTO *variable* statement instead of the READ *fd* one. They have to code a duplicate structure format: one for the file definition and one for the variable following INTO (as I highlighted in yellow in the sample code).

[image]

I wonder why you need to allocate extra storage (the WS-EMPL) since you already have the buffer EMPLOYEE-REC. Maybe the read buffer is read-only and you would not be able to use its fields as the receiver of statements (like ADD 1 TO EMPL-ID would be illegal).

What would be the typical use-cases of using READ *fd* into *var* and duplicating storage with the exact same structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *What would be the typical use-cases of using READ fd into var and duplicating storage with the exact same structure?*

Loading a table from a file.

Building a *virtual* record in memory containing data from multiple files, or, in some cases, from the same file where a primary record is followed by one or more related secondary records.

Historically, it was done for efficiency and may be retained for *style*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to allocate more memory. READ without INTO puts it into the area allocated in the DATA DIVISION.  READ INTO is useful if you, for your own reasons like "read-ahead" want to put an input record somewhere else. READ is the traditional method.