# Cobol file WRITE not allowed, file not open for output (status = 48) for file output-file

Tags: io, cobol

I have the following Cobol program that I am attempting to refactor it to be functional. The program is supposed to read an input file and output some stats. I am getting one major error, and one warning. I have added a bunch of my own code and it compiles.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
        PROGRAM-ID. STATMOLD.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
        INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
        FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT input-file ASSIGN TO "input.dat".
           SELECT output-file ASSIGN TO "output.dat".
       DATA DIVISION.
        FILE SECTION.
        FD input-file.
         01 INPUT-VALUE-RECORD.
           02 IN-X        PIC S9(6)V9(2).
           02 FILLER      PIC X(72).
        FD output-file.
         01 output-line    PIC X(80).

        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
         77 SUM-OF-X-SQR   PIC 9(14)V9(2).
         77 SUM-OF-X       PIC S9(10)V9(2).
         77 N              PIC S9(4).
         77 MEAN           PIC S9(6)V9(2).
         77 I              PIC S9(4).
         01 ARRAY-AREA.
           02 X           PIC S9(6)V9(2) OCCURS 1000 TIMES.
       
         01 OUTPUT-TITLE-LINE.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(28) VALUE
                        " MEAN AND STANDARD DEVIATION".
         01 OUTPUT-UNDERLINE.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(28) VALUE
                        "----------------------------".
         01 OUTPUT-COL-HEADS.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(11) VALUE "DATA VALUES".
         01 OUTPUT-DATA-LINE.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
           02 OUT-X       PIC -(6)9.9(2).
         01 OUTPUT-RESULTS-LINE-1.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(9) VALUE " MEAN=   ".
           02 OUT-MEAN    PIC -(6)9.9(2).
         01 OUTPUT-RESULTS-LINE-2.
           02 FILLER      PIC X(9) VALUE " STD DEV=".
           02 STD-DEVIATION    PIC -(6)9.9(2).   
           
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE, OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.
           MOVE ZERO TO IN-X.
           PERFORM PROC-BODY
             UNTIL IN-X IS = 999999.99.
           PERFORM END-OF-JOB.
       
       PROC-BODY.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-TITLE-LINE
               AFTER ADVANCING 0 LINES.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-UNDERLINE
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-COL-HEADS
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-UNDERLINE
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
           MOVE ZERO TO SUM-OF-X.
           READ INPUT-FILE INTO INPUT-VALUE-RECORD
              AT END PERFORM END-OF-JOB.
           PERFORM INPUT-LOOP
              VARYING N FROM 1 BY 1
              UNTIL N IS GREATER THAN 1000 OR IN-X IS NOT LESS THAN 999999.98.
           SUBTRACT 1 FROM N.
           DIVIDE N INTO SUM-OF-X GIVING MEAN ROUNDED.
           MOVE ZERO TO SUM-OF-X-SQR.
           PERFORM SUM-LOOP
              VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
              UNTIL I IS GREATER THAN N.
           COMPUTE STD-DEVIATION ROUNDED = (SUM-OF-X-SQR / N) ** 0.5.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-UNDERLINE
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
           MOVE MEAN TO OUT-MEAN.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-RESULTS-LINE-1
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-RESULTS-LINE-2
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
              
       INPUT-LOOP.
           MOVE IN-X TO X(N), OUT-X.
           WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM OUTPUT-DATA-LINE
              AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
           ADD X(N) TO SUM-OF-X.
           READ INPUT-FILE INTO INPUT-VALUE-RECORD
              AT END PERFORM END-OF-JOB.
       
       SUM-LOOP.
           COMPUTE SUM-OF-X-SQR = SUM-OF-X-SQR + (X(I) - MEAN) ** 2.
       
       END-OF-JOB.
           CLOSE INPUT-FILE, OUTPUT-FILE.
           STOP-RUN.
```

The error I am getting is:

```
libcob: error: WRITE not allowed, file not open for output (status = 48) for file output-file ('output_dat' => output.dat).
```

I believe the initialization is correct, but it's still not running to completion.

Separately, I am getting a COMPILATION warning , which says that there is move overlap at the following lines:

```
62 READ INPUT-FILE INTO INPUT-VALUE-RECORD
```

at the start of the prec body, and

```
87 READ INPUT-FILE INTO INPUT-VALUE-RECORD
```

in input-loop. I know that I can solve this with a temp variable but is there another way? and what is the solution to the WRITE not allowed error?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, i.e. as per my edit. And please clarify whether *this* code is giving you the error, which is hard to believe, or your *refactored* code, which you haven't posted. `INTO INPUT-VALUE-RECORD` is redundant in both cases. The `INTO` clause should refer to a `WORKING-STORAGE` variable. You don't need it here. See [read or read into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889533/read-or-read-into).

Comment: this code is giving me the EXACT runtime error I posted. I don't know what you think you know, because the error is in this code. if you had an issue with indentation, fine, but this is the code. The error is occuring in when I run it, it is not a compilation warning!

Comment: 'What I think I know' is that your question wasn't clear, and also that I have written two Cobol compilers. Thanks for clarifying. And who said anything about compilation warnings? Relax. Although surely 'move overlap' *is* a compilation warning?

Comment: Yes, that could have been clearer. THe overlap is occurring as a warning in compilation, and the write error is in runtime. I will edit the post to clarify

Comment: Well the WRITE error is very odd. Code looks OK, but remove the INTO clauses. Are you sure you're actually running this code? Recompile, re-test.

Comment: Recompiled and reran it a few times. No more Overlap error, so thanks for that, but the WRITE error is still showing up! Ive been pulling my hair out for an hour because of this, think I'm going crazy

Comment: Without looking in detail, I guess that the OPEN OUTPUT failed (but that should have given you an earlier error). Please specify.the exact compiler version and compile commands, and the rerun after adding --debug to get more information about the error.

Comment: I’m curious about `output_dat`. This doesn’t appear in your source code. Is there some JCL or external configuration that provides that? And do you have write access to such a file?  Is there by any change a *prior* error about opening it for output? Try deleting the output file and retesting.

Comment: I would assume you're falling through your code.  STOP-RUN is two words not one.  No hyphen.

Comment: yep, Jim nailed that. @JimCastro can you please change that to a full answer - ideally together with the way to verify it (either use a debugger and step through the code or compile with `-ftrace-all` then run with `COB_SET_TRACE=1`)? If you prefer I could do that (but I'd prefer you to do it :-).

Comment: @JimCastro Both my compilers would have caught that ;-)

Comment: @OP To clarify about `READ ... INTO ...`, `READ` reads into the data item named in the `FD`. So in your case `READ INPUT-FILE` is already going into `INPUT-VALUE-RECORD`. If you had a working-storage item named say `WS-INPUT-VALUE-RECORD`, you could write `READ INPUT-FILE INTO WS-INPUT-VALUE-RECORD`, which is fully equivalent to `READ INPUT-FILE. MOVE INPUT-VALUE-RECORD TO WS-INPUT-VALUE-RECORD`. OK?

Answer (score 1):

@jim-castro had the correct answer:

Because you had `STOP-RUN` (with a hyphen) instead of `STOP RUN` (without a hyphen), COBOL interpreted that as a paragraph name, and thus your `PERFORM END-OF-JOB` did not end the job, Instead, it fell through to the `PROC-BODY` paragraph, were it tried to write to the output file after it was closed.

Comment: Should possibly be moved to a community answer then...

Comment: @SimonSobisch I do not know how to do that.

Comment: You'd click on "edit" then check the "community wiki" option, then save.